# How restrained are we in terms of metatheories when working with higher order logics with full semantics?

Tags: lo.logic, metamathematics

When working in the realm of first order logic one can use very basic mathematical backgrounds(in reverse mathematical sense) to prove interesting things about more "structures".

- In what way does treatment of higher order logics force us to use more powerful backgrounds?